# Having trouble checking stdin in Python 3 in array

Tags: python-3.x, stdin, sys

If I do this, it returns `x` as `false` always. Why is that, could you please advise me?

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   valid = ["()", "[]", "{}"]
   x = True if line in valid else False
```

Comment: Iterating over a file object always generates lines that end with a newline character, unless it is the last line before end of file, and the last line does not end with a newline character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `str.rstrip` to remove the new line character at the end of each line:

```
import sys

# since there's one invariant `valid` list, define it here, outside the loop
valid = ["()", "[]", "{}"]

for line in sys.stdin:
   x = line.rstrip() in valid   #   no need for if ... else
   print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to :

```
x = True if line.rstrip() in valid else False
```